# How to fix my local ip address

Tags: dhcp, ip-address

I want my private IP address `192.168.xxx.xxx` to be fixed and do not change, Is it possible? I am using Ubuntu 14.04. 
I need it to work even when I change the network? Thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to static your IP

The following steps describes how to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 14.04.

You need to edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I have used `gedit` as an editor. If you don't have it installed you can replace it with `vim` or whichever you have.

```
sudo  gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then change to include the following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface lo inet interface
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.122
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
~
```

`eth0` is the regular ethernet interface
`address` is the static IP address you choose
`gateway` is usually the router's IP address
`dns-nameservers` is the dns server IP address, this is needed for domain name resolution

After the change you can either reboot or run

```
sudo ifdown eth0

sudo  ifup  eth0
```

Check now. Run terminal and type:

```
ifconfig
```

Comment: ubuntu LTS 14.04

Comment: do you know your gateway and subnet?

Comment: @Hunter Please do  not use answers as a comment. This is not the right way to ask a question. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//askubuntu.com/privileges/comment). I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: not  sure subnet 192168.1.255 and getway 192.168.1.1

Comment: @Tim my reputation is less than 50 so i cannot comment on the question ... that's why i have asked for clarification in my answer

Comment: @Hunter I know you can't, but you're not meant to use answers instead of comments. Answer some posts and you'll soon have enough to comment.

Comment: @Tim u are making it difficult for me to comment  :(

Comment: @Hunter I have undone my vote, and upvoted. Answer another question and you'll have plenty to comment :)

Comment: will this work even when I change my wifi network connection?

Comment: My answer was for Ethernet  however you can replace 'eth0' with your wifi interface, probably 'wlan0' and try it.

Answer (score 4):

In the dash search for "Network Connections" and open the application, from here select the interface you want and click on the edit button:

[image: Network Settings]

From here click on the IPv4 Settings tab and change the method from Automatic DHCP to Manual and enter your network setting to something like this:

[image: Network Settings 2]

Now all you need to do is save the settings and restart the network connection and the ip should be statically set.

Please bare in mind that these settings are specific to Ubuntu and if, for example another device on the network connects using your static IP through DHCP you won't be able to connect using your static IP because it would have already been assigned.

Comment: But I don't have lan so I will choose a speccific wifi connection but I need  it to be static even for other future wifi connections

Comment: The only way to make your connection truly static would be by using DHCP Reservation on your router to statically set the same IP address to the network card on your computer using its MAC address but that is out of scope on Ask Ubuntu because it is related to networking hardware/software and not Ubuntu directly.

Comment: @LolaLoulita That won't work on Wireless if you have multiple wifi networks you use.  To do that you have to tell the system to NOT let NetworkManager handle the network connection, and have the standard `/etc/network/interfaces` file determine addressing as well as using command line tools to manage the wireless connection.  Static IP and Wifi also do not go well together.

Answer (score -3):

You can set it from your box.

Just connect to it as an administrator and look for advanced options.

There should be a way to ask your box to give your computer always the same IP address.

Comment: Yes, it is called DHCP Reservation but this is out of scope on Ask Ubuntu because it is network related and doesn't affect Ubuntu directly.

Comment: @Jerem this doesn't answer the question.